# Python: 1 to 100 using While statement in 10 rows

Tags: python

I am trying to print 1 to 100 using while statement.
Well, that is easy

```
 n =100
 i=0
 while i<n:
      i=i+1
      print (i)
```

But the problem is how to put 1 to 10 in a row, 11 to 20 in a row, and finally to 91 to 100 in  a row.
Could you tell me the way?

Comment: As a heads up, Python is case sensitive, so the code you have posted above will not work. I'm sure this is just because you have written the code into here but in future, please format the code here exactly as it looks when you run it.

Comment: You've completely changed your question. It's not even related to python anymore.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include a new problem. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `zip` and `iter`:

```
lst = [i for i in zip(*[iter(range(1,101))]*10)]
```

Change the last number to the size of the chunks you want; in this case it is `10`.

Output:

```
>>> lst
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), (21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30), (31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40), (41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50), (51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60), (61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70), (71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80), (81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90), (91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100)]
```

Then print each number inside the list:

```
for i in lst:
    for j in i:
        print(j, end=" ")
    print()
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 
61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 
71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 
81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 
91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

So overall you have:

```
lst = [i for i in zip(*[iter(range(1,101))]*10)]

for i in lst:
    for j in i:
        print(j, end=" ")
    print()
```

**EDIT**:

As someone mentioned this only works in python 3. It can be done in python 2 by simply changing `end=" "` to `,`:

```
lst = [i for i in zip(*[iter(range(1,101))]*10)]

for i in lst:
    for j in i:
        print j,
    print
```

**EDIT 2:**

To do this with a `while` loop:

```
counter = 1
n = 100

while counter < n+1:

    if counter % 10 == 0:
        print(counter)
    else:
        print(counter, end=" ") #Change this line to print counter, for python version 2
    counter += 1
```

Comment: You do provide the correct answer, but you're creating an array then looping over that twice. That nested for loop is quite inefficient in python, just fyi,

Comment: I understand what you mean but it's fast enough for this specific case. Thanks!

Comment: Also, OP was explicitly asking for a `while` loop.

Comment: Missed that, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

You were pretty close, you were missing an `if` statement and changing the `end` for the [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#print) statement to `" "` as the default is `'\n'`.

> print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)

```
N = 20
I = 1
while I <= N:
    if I % 10 > 0:
        print(I, end = " ")
    else:
        print(I)
    I += 1

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

*Note:*
`I += 1` in python is simpler than doing `I=I+1`. Also works for multiplication.

**Python 2.x**

The previous code works for Python 3.x as mentioned in the comments by @idjaw. For python 2.x, to use `print` as a function rather than a statement (i.e. `print()`) the followring needs to be imported at the start of the script.

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: Sorry for coming back. I ran this in 2.7.10 and I'm getting a syntax error because of the `end` in the print statement. How did you get it running in Python 2? I'm just curious. Don't mean to be annoying.

Comment: I don't have python 2.7, only 3.5. According to the docs it seems there, if it actually doesn't work I can include it's only for 3.x. Could it be listed in the docs but can't be changed?

Comment: Myster solved. Read the note at the bottom of the `print` description [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print). To use it in Python 2 you need to import from future. But everyone should be using 3 anyway, right? :P

Comment: *Should* but I'll add it just in case. Thank you for investigating this.

Comment: Np! FWIW I had +1 a while ago anyway. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is false. i is not I. indent is false too

```
def print_numbers(min_nu, max_nu, step):
   import sys
   if sys.version_info > (3,0):
      my_xrange = range
   else:
      my_xrange = xrange
   for i in my_xrange(min_nu, max_nu, step):
      buff = [str(j) for j in my_xrange(i, i + step)]
      print(" ".join(buff))

print_numbers(1, 100, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this this should do the job:

```
def solution_01(n):
    index = 0
    row = ''
    while index <=n:
        index+=1
        row += ' '+str(index) 
        if index%10 == 0:
            print row
            row = ''

solution_01(100)
```

Gives the output:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70
 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80
 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90
 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

Answer (score 1):

A double nested `for` loop should do the trick for u:

```
>>> for i in range(1,101,10):
        for j in range(i, i+10):
            print(j, end=' ')
        print()


1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 
61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 
71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 
81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 
91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

Or only using `while` loop, if that's your requirement:

```
>>> i = j = 1
>>> 
>>> while i < 101:
        while j < i+10:
            print(j, end=' ')
            j += 1
        i += 10
        print()


1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 
61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 
71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 
81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 
91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[y for y in range(10 * x + 1, 10 + 10 * x + 1)] for x in range(10)]
```

Comment: I don't see a `while` loop in this code-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

## print numbers from 100 to 0 with one loop

```
for i in range(100,-1,-1):
    if i%10==0 and i!=100:
        print(i)
    else:
        print(i,end=", ")
```

output:

100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90

89, 88, 87, 86, 85, 84, 83, 82, 81, 80

79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70

69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 61, 60

59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50

49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40

39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30

29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20

19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10

9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0

Answer (score 0):

```
 x=1
    while x<101:
        if x%10==0:
            print(" {}{}".format(x,"\n"),end="" )
        else:
            print(" {}".format(x),end="")
            
        x+=1
```

output:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70
 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80
 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90
 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).